# QGIS 2.18, gives Invalid Data source

Tags: shapefile, qgis-2.18, data-source

Using QGIS 2.18.14, add vector layer, open a shapefile, gives:

`Invalid Data Source: FILE.shp is not a valid or recognized data source`

This FILE.shp was OK on QGIS 2.12. Same result for other .shp files as well as other vector files like .gpx and .gmt. There was no problems reading those files in QGIS 2.12. Reading raster files is OK.

I'm running this on Linux, Fedora 27, 4.13.16-302.fc27.x86_64

This is not a problem on another Fedora 27.

All has been updated (dnf update).

I have not been able to Google a solution to this problem.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have all the shapefile files, not just the .shp file?

Comment: Do you get the same error using ogrinfo? From the command line execute ogrinfo -al your_shape_file